# TypeError: String indices must be integers, not str. What am I not seeing?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, unit-testing, python-unittest

I am testing some code and want to test to see if the API is properly formatted. Below is the dictionary that I am using to test.

```
self.test_query_values_positive = {
    'DriverAge' : 33,
    'PickUpCity' : 'Tampa',
    'CarType' : 'luxury'
}
```

Here is the unit test in question:

```
def testQueryCreationPositive(self):
    test_query = self.testDBM.create_http_query(self.test_query_values_positive)
    self.assertEqual("some.api/findCar?city=Tampa&class=luxury",
                     self.testDBM.create_http_query(test_query))
```

And here is the function I am calling from the testDBM object

```
def create_http_query(self, slots):
    base_url = 'some.api/findCar?'
    query = None
    if self.verify_age(slots['DriverAge']):
        pickup = slots['PickUpCity'].title()
        car_type = slots['CarType'].lower()
        query = '{0}city={1}&class={2}'.format(base_url, pickup, car_type)
    else:
        query = None
    return query
```

From this, I am getting a TypeError as shown below:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

What am I not seeing?  I have a negative test right below it that runs perfectly fine, but this one doesn't.  Why is that?

EDIT:  I forgot to say that the line in question is:

```
if self.verify_age(slots['DriverAge']):
```

It seems to run fine other than that.

Comment: `test_query` is either a string or `None`, so when the next line is executed, the `slots` argument of `create_http_query` is either a string or `None` (string in your case).

Answer (score 1):

```
def testQueryCreationPositive(self):
    test_query = self.testDBM.create_http_query(self.test_query_values_positive)
    self.assertEqual("some.api/findCar?city=Tampa&class=luxury",
                     self.testDBM.create_http_query(test_query))  # this line is bad
```

This is what you want:

```
self.assertEqual("some.api/findCar?city=Tampa&class=luxury", test_query)
```